# JQuery to set event to checkbox checked/unchecked

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Rates">Rates<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="RatesSpecific">Rates (All-In-Rate, PV01)<br />
```

These NEED to stay checkboxes (because there are more than just these 2). But how do I set a JQuery event to only have one of these checked at one time, and grey the other one out when the other is checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes the checkbox element act like a radio button, but they need to be sibling elements.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
   if($(this).prop('checked')){
     $(this).siblings("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false);
   }
});
```

Maybe you should consider using radio buttons?

Comment: How do I make them siblings? And what if I have two sets of siblings?

Comment: If not sliblings, then add the same class to them. $("input.checkbox_class").not($(this)).removeAttr("checked");

Answer (score 1):

Give them an ID attribute, then use

```
$(function() {
  $("#rates").change(function() {
    updateCheckBoxes();
  });

  $("#ratesSpecific").change(function() {
    updateCheckBoxes();
  });
});

function updateCheckBoxes() {
  if ($("#rates").val()) {
    $("#ratesSpecific").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  } else {
    $("#ratesSpecific").removeAttr("disabled");
  }

  if ($("#ratesSpecific").val()) {
    $("#rates").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  } else {
    $("#rates").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle page:  http://jsfiddle.net/h682v/1/

I have put several examples in there including disable of one based on status of another.

Note that one part unchecks based on others (Tasks unchecks disables bottom check boxes and unchecks the one), while another just disables.  Check all the top ones (*Tasks) and then the bottom two are active.

In this one: http://jsfiddle.net/h682v/2/ it also unchecks the last one and disables it when any previous one is unchecked.

EDIT: Note that the way I did this if you add more checkboxes, they get handled correctly - hopefully that will help given you say you have "other" checkboxes as well.